# Getting Community Page into MavensMate & GitHub

Tags: community, mavensmate, github

I created a custom record detail page for a custom object in the Napili community I'm working on. I use MavensMate with Sublime Text 3 and our code is saved in GitHub.

How do I pull down the community page onto my local machine so that I can then push it into GitHub?

I've done it with other things I've created in salesforce by updating the project but that didn't work for the community page.

Comment: What is the url when you view it in the UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lightning Pages for community is still not exposed for packaging .You will able to pull it for lightning App Builder but not for community builder pages .

You will need to wait for few weeks(probably 2 week for sandbox) to allow winter 17 release to roll out in your sandbox to have ability to export it .

Please see below screenshots from winter 17 pre-release org on how this can be achieved

[image]

[image]

Once its exposed as Lightning Page you will see this in Flexipages just like others .

Comment: How to create custom template for Napili community . I saw somewhere, but not getting it back. ?

Comment: @Ankuli please post as a different question can help you